# How do I create this kind of of overlap in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

[image: I'm looking to overlap two logos and have them separated by a slash]

I'm looking to overlap two logos and have them separated by a slash as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible way to handle this is to put a thick, white-colored stroke on your "slash" object. That way the two logos underneath the slash don't need to be trimmed/edited to remove the parts of the artwork you don't want to show.

Answer (score 0):

Create two simple shapes on top of your logos to cover the parts that you want to be visible. Select the first shape and the first logo and make a clipping mask. This will result in your first logo being visible inside the first simple shape. Repeat the same technique to clip the second logo.